# Transitions and text attributes in a div in D3.js

Tags: html, text, d3.js, transition

I'm trying to do some simple text boxes in D3, and using another q & a on SO I've figured out that I need to use the foreignObject and wrap the text up in a div. That's all fine. What I want to do then is update the text by clicking some other thing. I can update the text itself, but not the size or the colour of it. That can't be right. Here's my code.

```
    var svg = d3.select("body")
        .append("svg")
        .attr("width", w)
        .attr("height", h);

//add some text for clicking
    svg.append("text")
    .attr("x", "260")
    .attr("y", "40")
    .attr("font-family","sans-serif")
    .attr("font-size", "18")
    .attr("fill", "black")
    .attr("id", "clickone")
    .text("Click this")
    ;      

//this is the foreignObject with the original text

       svg.append('foreignObject')
           .attr('x', 40)
           .attr('y', 100)
           .attr('width', 180)
           .attr('height', 100)
           .append("xhtml:body")
           .attr("id","words")
           .html('<div style="width: 160px;"><p>Old text old text old text old text old text old text<p></div>');

//and here's the click and transition                  

    svg.select("svg #clickone")
        .on("click", function() {

    svg.select('p')
    .transition()
    .delay(500)
    .text("new text new text new text new text new text")
    .attr("fill","red")
    .attr("font-size","20")

    })
```

;

So in that example, the text updates, the transition delays, but the colour and size don't change. There's no CSS or anything, just the code. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried `.style()` instead of `.attr()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `<p>` tag doesn't have a `fill` or a `font-size` attribute. It does have a css style attribute which you can use to do more or less the same thing and which you can change with [`transition.style`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Transitions#wiki-style)

This could look like this:

```
svg.select("svg #clickone").on("click", function() {
    svg.select('p')
    .transition()
    .duration(2500)
    .text("new text new text new text new text new text")
    .style("background-color","red")
    .style("font-size","20px")
});
```